# TextBox/TextArea Text getting cut off

Tags: asp.net, textbox, textarea

I'm trying to use a textbox or textarea to show a preview of some notes when a row is selected in an adjacent grid in an Asp.Net application.  The problem is, no matter how much text I enter in the bound field, the text gets cut off in the preview text control.  I'm testing in IE.  These are the two controls I have experimented with that have provided the same results, as well as the CSS used to for the control:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" class="textArea" ID="Notes_TextBox" TextMode="MultiLine" ReadOnly="true" Rows="20" />
<textarea runat="server" class="textArea" id="Notes_TextArea" rows="3" cols="22" readonly="readonly" />

.textArea
{
    border: 1px solid #b5bcc7;
    height: 380px;
    background-color: #F7FCFF;
    color: Gray;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The functionality I'm looking for is to have the readonly text box/area there at all times without a scroll bar showing and when the text is larger than the box, the scroll bar should appear allowing viewing of all the text in the field.

Please let me know if you more information would be helpful or if you have any suggestions for me.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with the underlying data.  The Notes field of the underlying object was truncated by default and there's another field called LongNotes that contained the full text.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it figured out. I do think auto is still the proper css style to use though... =]

Answer (score 2):

Change the `overflow` style to `auto` from `hidden`. That seems to work properly in IE8 for me.

```
.textArea
{
    border: 1px solid #b5bcc7;
    height: 380px;
    background-color: #F7FCFF;
    color: Gray;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    padding: 2px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the text gets truncated and the scrollbar never shows up even if I change the overflow to auto.